# Dynamically change wordpress post title with javascript during post creation

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have a custom wordpress post type which include a date input. I want to dynamically set the post title depending of the date input value like this : "05/05/2023 event".

I succeed with javascript to retrieve date from date input and set title to the edit form with

```js
const inputTitleElm = document.querySelector("[name='post_title']");
inputTitleElm.value = `${eventDate} event`;
```

But it is not working as expected, if I want to save/publish this custom post, wordpress doesn't use the post title I previously set with javascript and create an "auto draft" title.

To recap:

- I am not using gutenberg for this post type.
- I succeed to display the new title value in the edit form
- The title dynamically set with javascript to the edit form is not used by wordpress to save the post

Comment: How are you getting `eventDate`? Did you check the JS console for errors?

Comment: It is calculated in javascript with date input value I have no error because everythings works find in javascript the issue come from wp side

Comment: Hard to tell without being able to check the app, but WP might be checking to see if you've interacted with/typed in the title input, and throwing its input away otherwise. You see this antipattern occasionally when autofills fail to save. Try clicking in the input before submitting, and then try adding one character then backspacing; if one of those fixes it, you'll have to do something to trick WP into thinking you typed into the field.

Comment: I try to dispatch a focusout event no success, with blur it works the first time I change the title but not the other times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally succeed to trick wordpress making him think I manually edit title.
To do it, after I dynamically change post_title input, I dispatch click and blur event to simulate user click inside and outside input like this :

```js
const clickEvent = new Event('click');
const blurEvent = new Event('blur');
inputTitleElm.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
inputTitleElm.dispatchEvent(blurEvent);
```

Doing so, my post title is update and correct when I save a draft or publish my custom post type.

Be sure that your input don't have disabled attribute because thoses dispatch won't work as expected.